# Restrict access to a NTFS folder for everyone except user or group

Tags: windows-7

We need to set access to specific folders, for specific people. The problem is that "Everyone" group and "Administrators" group are added in the security tab, and their allow list is checked and grayed out.

Is it possible in this (sub)folders to restrict permission even for administrators? (since almost all are administrators in this system anyway)

Comment: Is this is a machine that is joined to a domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove inherited permissions (Folder properties->Security tab->Advanced->Permissions tab->Change permissions, uncheck "Include inheritable permissions from this objects parent") and then add the necessary users or groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this checkbox is also checked and grayed out on every folder I checked!

Comment: Even in the window that opens when you click the "Change permissions" button in the "Advanced security settings" window? On my computer, the checkbox is greyed out in the first "advanced security settings" window only. Are you the owner of the folder?

Comment: Yes, I even tried creating new folders, even at the root of the drive, and at a different drive, its always the same deal, I can't understand why

Comment: So it was grayed out because on the outside it only displays the value, I had to click change permissions to actually alter it, accepting the answer, thanks!